# VBA create an array from data held in a row in a spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to create an array from a range I specify where the range is part of a row instead of a column.

I have tried:

```
Dim mCH As Variant
    
    mCH = Range("A1:F1").Value
    
    For n = 1 To UBound(mCH)
        Debug.Print mCH(n, 1)
    Next n
```

I expected 6 values to be printed to the immediate window with the values in the first 6 columns of row 1, but the array only contains one value, the value in A1

when I arrange the values in a column and do the following it works:

```
Dim mCH As Variant
    
    mCH = Range("A1:A6").Value
    
    For n = 1 To UBound(mCH)
        Debug.Print mCH(n, 1)
    Next n
```

but I cannot arrange the data in this way for my purpose as I want to create an array from the first 6 column headings

Comment: Try changing this line `Debug.Print mCH(n, 1)` to this: `Debug.Print mCH(1, n)`.

Comment: And `For n = 1 To UBound(mCH,2)` - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function)

Answer (score 3):

### Loop Through Columns of a 2D One-Based Array

- If a given single-area range (`rg`) has more than one cell, you can write its values to a 2D one-based array (`Data`) by simply using the following:

  ```
  Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
  ```
- The number of rows (or the upper limit (size) of the 1st dimension) of this array can be retrieved with `UBound(Data)` which is short for **`UBound(Data, 1)`** which is equal to `rg.Rows.Count`.
- The number of columns (or the upper limit (size) of the 2nd dimension) of this array can be retrieved only with **`UBound(Data, 2)`** which is equal to `rg.Columns.Count`.
- If you want to retrieve the elements from the 1st row, you need to loop through the columns while the row stays `1`:

  ```
   Dim c As Long

   For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
       Debug.Print Data(1, c) 
   Next c
  ```
- Applying the previous to your example, you would use the following:

  ```
   Dim mCH() As Variant: mCH = Range("A1:F1").Value

   Dim n As Long 

   For n = 1 To UBound(mCH, 2)
       Debug.Print mCH(1, n)
   Next n
  ```